# Why is it better to use the default Object equals method in Java?

Tags: java, overriding, overloading, equals

Why is it considered better to use the default **Object `equals`** method in Java and modify it so it will work for a specific class (by validating with `instanceof` and using type casting):

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
   boolean isEqual = false;

   if ((otherObject != null) && (otherObject instanceof myClass))
      {
         myClass classObject = (myClass)otherObject;

         if (.....) //checking if equal
         {
            .....
}
```

instead of overloading it with a new `equals` method specific for each class that needs to use `equals`:

```
public boolean equals(myClass classObject)
```

Comment: It is not better, it just checks for the real meaning of equality.

Comment: I think OP asks why `equals(Object)` and not `equals(MyClass)` is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of `Object.equals()` is `public boolean equals(Object)`. If you define a method `public boolean equals(MyClass)`, you're adding a new method, with a different signature, instead of overriding (or redefining, if you prefer) the `Object.equals()` method.

Since all the collections call the `Object.equals()` method, your new method would never be called by anybody except your own code, and would thus be almost useless. For example, if you create a `Set<MyClass>`, it will consider that two instances are different, although your `equals(MyClass)` method considers them equal.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming that polymorphism will call the right method, maybe you can explain why this is not the case.

Comment: @sjr.. He has already explained it. There is no point of mixing it with dynamic dispatch, as it is not valid overriding. Always `Object` class method will be invoked by the Collections that use `equals` to compare object.

Comment: I think if you know Java inside out, this is a fine answer. I think the OP doesn't so this might be news for him.

Comment: The thing is I didn't think about it as a general `equals` method, but as a class-specific one. From what I understand `equals(Object)` is better because it's a general comparison method. But when I only use 1 superclass and 3 derived classes, it doesn't really matter. Am I right?

Comment: You can define an `equals(MyClass)` method. Just be aware that it won't be used by the standard collections, but only by your own code. For example, if you create a `Set<MyClass>`, it will consider that two instances are different, although your equals(MyClass) method considers them equal.

Comment: I see...can you add your last comment to your answer? I didn't get it at first because I thought that what you're saying is that my overloaded method will *never* be called, even by my own class/code.

Answer (score 1):

It is because most classes in Java (lists, queues, maps etc.) use the `boolean equals(Object obj)` method. At the time when Java was being designed way back in the nineties, Generics did not exist.

Comparison methods using for example the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), were updated to support generics, and thus take the right type (avoiding the `instanceof`) of your class directly. `Object.equals()` just takes a generic `Object`.

If you overload `.equals()` with new signatures, the other collections won't know about your new `equals()` methods and will still call the old original one provided by `Object`, so you have to stick with that and use `instanceof`. Remember overloading does not have the same effect of overriding. In overriding the subclass method gets called, since it has exactly the same signature. In overloading, you are just providing alternative functionality with a different signature, so the caller has to know about it.

Alternatively, instead of using the `equals()` method, maybe you can change your code a little to use the newer comparison methods with generics. Most collections have been updated to support `Comparator`, `Comparable` etc. with Generics too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I understand why it should be overridden and not overloaded.

Comment: Comparable was introduced in Java 2, long before the addition of generics in Java 5 where Compable and the entire collections framework was retrofitted with generics without loss of backward compatibility.

Comment: @meriton Yes `Comparable` was always there but it was updated to Generics with Java 5, while `.equals()` was not and still requires `instanceof` if you want to compare types. Sorry if the wording was slightly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `public boolean equals(MyClass classObject)` you are **overloading**.
So your method will not be called as it does not **override**
You could create such a method but you would also need `equal(Object)` as well in order for everything to function properly (Collections etc).

The only reason why you would be interested for such a method is for performance. But I don't think that nowadays you have an issue using `equals(Object)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the equals method for your class. When your override a method, you can't change the method arguments, can't change the return type, and can't make the method accessibility more restrictive.